# Gradle-Android: Where is the classpath() coming from?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Here is the root **build.gradle** file of an android app. I want to ask where does the *classpath()* method is declared. I guess in Project but I cant find it in the [reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N15035).

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Interface [ScriptHandler](http://org.gradle.api.initialization.dsl.ScriptHandler), `classpath` is the configuration's value of `public static final String CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION "classpath"`.

You can call it via `buildscript.CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION` as `buildscript` returns a `ScriptHandler`.